# Wordpress add script to footer for specific category (archive and posts)

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to add a google ad script for specific category only. The code should be and in the archives page for that category and the posts of that category.

Here is the code I am using in my functions.php file

```
add_action('wp_footer','MY_FUNCTION');
function MY_FUNCTION(){
   if ( is_category(309) ){
    echo '<script>the script</script>';
}
?>
```

but for some reason it breaks the site

Comment: you should write javascript code in `<script>` tag instead of text, try to add something meaning full like `alert('script working')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use include instead of echo. Store the Script in a separate php file and the call that file via include.

it won't break the site.

For examble,

create a script.php file and add the script. The call the file via include.

```
add_action('wp_footer','MY_FUNCTION');
function MY_FUNCTION(){
if ( is_category(309) ){
include 'script.php';}
```

Comment: Thanks Sathya. i will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can add "SOGO Add Script" plugin to use google ads script. It allows you to use javascript in header or footer section directly into your specified page.

Comment: Thanks Fahad Razi. But the plugin from wordpress site says: This plugin hasn’t been tested with the latest 3 major releases of WordPress. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.

Comment: you can use it, or search for any plugin that allow you to add javascript